# Add Div ID to YouTube iFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I am trying to detect if there is a YouTube iframe on the page and if so, add a div id so that fitvids.js will make it scale to it's container. I am not able to get the js to append the div id to the iframe:

```
<script src="/js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery.fitvids.js"></script>
<script>
 $(window).load(function () {
 $("iframe").attr('id','resp-video');
 });
</script>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $("#resp-video").fitVids();
 });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('iframe[src*="youtube.com"]').each(function() {
        $(this).closest("div").attr("id","resp-video");
    });
```

Comment: I replaced the window load function with this and still no luck. I don't see any errors in the console.

Comment: you have to replace the newid by resp-video.. updated answer check now

Comment: Wow I swear I replaced that. Thank you for the help!